# Is there a way to improve the voice chat quality?

Tags: apex-legends

The quality of the voice chat in Apex is really bad. Much much worse than Discord or similar software. Is this a limitation of the game or can this be changed through the settings.

EDIT: I voice chatted with friends at the same time over Discord and the quality was worlds apart. Therefore a hardware problem seems extremely unlikely.

Comment: Can you name any voice chat software in which you always understood everyone perfectly fine? Because I can't, and I used a few. There is always some partner whose quality is bad, while everyone else is perfectly fine

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: This is a loaded question. I never made the claim that there exists one software that provides perfect quality for all users and all hardware. I made the claim that I have a small set of people with whom I had perfect quality using Discord (or Overwatch voice chat) and with the *same* people (and hardware) had horrible quality using Apex's voice chat. Thus I conclude that Apex's voice chat is the culprit.

Comment: i can't post an answer because it's protected now. Yes the voice chat quality in APEX is very low for a few reasons. (1) it uses a very low bitrate codec, much lower than discord (which is a configurable bitrate, but always higher than apex). (2) there is a bug which causes horrible capture quality with some devices, i was able to mitigate this somewhat by dramatically lowering my control panel gain for the mic, (3) the apex codec handles bass poorly, so EQ it out, (4) there is a bug where a player glitches and everything comes out as nasty robotic noise. this resets on the next match.

Answer (score 5):

No, the only in-game setting for voice chat is volume. This would be a limitation to how Respawn handles their voice chat.

There have been moments where other players mics sound like a broken record, and that *could be* tied to server lag which a lot of players are reporting.

Comment: I added a note which clarifies that it is highly unlikely to be a hardware problem. I am surprised that a AAA title has voice quality this bad, especially considering that the codecs are there and open source (Opus). Therefore I suspected that it is a configuration problem.

Comment: VanBuzzKill is wrong, I run a blue yeti mic through Ableton Live and can test my sound live. It is extremely high quality. I know what I sound like in Discord and to my stream. When I test my mic in Origin it sounds like I'm using 96kbps quality mp3 sound (192kbps is CD quality sound).

Comment: I'll second @Anon's comment here. It's more likely the poor audio codec and internet lag causing the audio issues.

Comment: Disagree with this answer. On every other game/software, voice chat is perfect. But on Apex, it's so bad and sounds like someone is using a very cheap mic or something. It's definitely not an hardware issue

Comment: To all of the comments, the fact still remains there is no in game way to mess with mic settings which is what the question is ultimately asking. The rest was personal opinion based on hearing other peoples mics.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to your question, @VanBuzzKill. I'll remove my answer as it now duplicates yours... :)